# I am not able to print my polynomial expression using linked list

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, polynomials

```
void create(struct node *head);                   //declaring functions
void display(struct node *head);     
struct node                                 //creating a struct datatype for nodes        
{
 int coeff;
 int power;
 struct node* next;
};
  struct node* poly1=NULL;               //head pointer for a sample polynomial

  void main()
 {
   int coeff,power,deg,i;
   clrscr();                                              //main function
   printf("\n enter polynomial 1 ");
   create(poly1);
   display(poly1);
   getch();
 }

  void create(struct node *head)
 {
  struct node *newnode,*temp;
  int exp,num,n,i;
  printf("\n enter no. of terms in your expression=");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(newnode));
   newnode->next=NULL;
   printf("\n enter power=");
   scanf("%d",&exp);
   newnode->power=exp;
   printf("\n enter coefficient=");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   newnode->coeff=num;
    if(head==NULL)
     head=newnode;
    else
     {
      temp=head;
      while(temp->next!=NULL)
      {
       temp=temp->next;
      }
       temp->next=newnode;
     }
 }
}
 void display(struct node *head)
 {
  struct node *temp;
  temp=head;                                                 
  while(temp->next!=NULL)
  {
   printf("%dx^%d",temp->coeff,temp->power);
   temp=temp->next;
   }
 }
```

My code compilation shows no errors or warnings but I am not able to print my polynomial function. The display function is printing just 0 x^ 0 or no values at all, I have tried many things but it is not working, can someone point out what should I do to correct it. I am using C language.

Comment: No warnings? I get tons of warnings for your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

> My code compilation shows no errors or warnings

That's very strange. After adding missing includes and commenting out `getch` and `clrscr` this is the compiler output and it's without even enabling the (almost mandatory) flags `-Wall -Wextra`:

```
$ gcc main.c
main.c:4:20: warning: ‘struct node’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
    4 | void create(struct node *head);                   //declaring functions
      |                    ^~~~
main.c:5:21: warning: ‘struct node’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
    5 | void display(struct node *head);
      |                     ^~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:19:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   19 |    create(poly1);
      |           ^~~~~
      |           |
      |           struct node *
main.c:4:26: note: expected ‘struct node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
    4 | void create(struct node *head);                   //declaring functions
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
main.c:20:12: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘display’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   20 |    display(poly1);
      |            ^~~~~
      |            |
      |            struct node *
main.c:5:27: note: expected ‘struct node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct node *’
    5 | void display(struct node *head);
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
main.c: At top level:
main.c:24:8: error: conflicting types for ‘create’
   24 |   void create(struct node *head)
      |        ^~~~~~
main.c:4:6: note: previous declaration of ‘create’ was here
    4 | void create(struct node *head);                   //declaring functions
      |      ^~~~~~
main.c:53:7: error: conflicting types for ‘display’
   53 |  void display(struct node *head)
      |       ^~~~~~~
main.c:5:6: note: previous declaration of ‘display’ was here
    5 | void display(struct node *head);
```

Your compiler seems to be seriously outdated.

There seems to be many issues with your code, but one obvious is this:

```
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(newnode));
```

The casting is bad practice, but should not cause any actual problems, but the argument to sizeof is wrong. It should be:

```
newnode=malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you pass the pointer by value

```
create(poly1);
```

to your function

```
void create(struct node *head)
```

then you set `head`

```
head=newnode;
```

but are only modifying the local variable `head`, while you *want* to modify `poly1`.

One possibility is to pass a double pointer like this:

```
 create(&poly1);
 ...
 void create(struct node **head)
 ...
 if (*head == NULL)
     *head = newnode;
```

Now you really modify the global variable `poly1`, which is what you want.